# It's possible to Index by google page's anchor (#) as a page

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing, google-index, anchor

I have a frequent question page (www.example.com/faq#top-inviters), that has every question bellow an anchor. Google index all the content, but when I find a specific question google give the parent page (www.example.com/faq).

It's possible to index every anchor as a single page?

Comment: It isn't a page, so how would that work?

Comment: Besides, that would be terrible url structure.

Comment: Google doesn't index those separately, so if you're using them all for the same page, then that's totally fine. Refer - https://twitter.com/JohnMu/status/1052621056488431616 by John Mueller

Answer (score 2):

John who is Webmaster Trends Analyst at Google has given a answer for your question.

> We don't index those separately, so if you're using them all for the
>   same page, then that's totally fine :)

Source : https://twitter.com/JohnMu/status/1052621056488431616